# Deploy SQL Server Reports Locally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am very new to SQL server Reporting Services.I have developed reports in SQL Server Reporting.now Where do i deploy them in order to use them into my asp.net web application?

Comment: @MitchWheat how ? any step by step guide?

Comment: Is the documentation unclear or unhelpful? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281175.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include the report in your ASP.NET application, here you will need to use a custom control however, Microsoft does not provide a custom control like crystal report viewer custom control, in fact you will find it deployed in the samples directory of Reporting service. The custom control is located at

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Reporting Services\Samples\Applications\ReportViewer
```

You can just go and open that project and compile it and use the ReportViewer DLL in your ASP.NET application. This can be done by opening your toolbox, then click Add/remove and click browse and select the ReportViewer.DLL I included the source and the DLL in the source in case you cannot find it or you didn't install the sample applications of reporting service. Anyway after selecting the DLL you have to select the custom control from the list.

You will find the name of the Custom Control ReportViewer `"Microsoft Sample Report Viewer Application"`

When you are done, just include the custom control in your ASP.NET page and change the following properties.

- First you have to select the report path and this should be something
  like :- My Reports/Report1 - exactly the sample folder you deployed
  your reports in.
- Second you have to edit the ServerURL and here you enter your
  reporting service location http://localhost/reportserver/ this is the
  reporting server location, while /reports is the report server web management so take care not to get mixed up.

Once both are done, you can start viewing your report by accessing your ASP.NET web page.

Now enter the location of your web application and choose the asp.net page that contains the custom control